# Android Wear Channel API status code 8

Tags: java, android, wear-os, channel

I'm trying to send a file from the phone to the wear app, on the phone I'm sending the file as follows with a successful status.

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodesResult = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
for (Node node : nodesResult.getNodes()) {
      ChannelApi.OpenChannelResult result = Wearable.ChannelApi.openChannel(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "/songs").await();
      Channel channel = result.getChannel();
File file = new File(AppUtils.getDownloadsDir(getApplicationContext()),"lift.mp3");
      Log.d(TAG, "call: " + file.canRead() + Uri.fromFile(file) + file.length());
      channel.sendFile(mGoogleApiClient, Uri.fromFile(file)).setResultCallback(
          new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
              Log.d(TAG, "onResult: " + status.isSuccess() + " " + status.getStatusMessage());
            }
          }
      );
      Log.d(TAG, "Node " + node.getId() + node.getDisplayName() + node.isNearby());
    }
```

On the wear side however, onChannelOpened is getting called with the correct path, I create a file, but when calling Channel.receiveFile I get a status code of 8 (INTERNAL_ERROR) in the resultCallback status.

```
public void onChannelOpened(final Channel channel) {
 if (channel.getPath().equals("/songs")) {

  try {
    final File outFile = prepareFile("wild.mp3");
    if (outFile == null || !outFile.exists()) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create file ");
      return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onChannelOpened: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    channel.receiveFile(mGoogleApiClient, Uri.fromFile(outFile), false).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
          @Override
          public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
              Log.e(TAG, "receiveFile(): Failed to receive file with "
                  + "status code = " + statusCode
                  + ", and status: " + status.getStatus());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The application id was already the same when this was happening, however the key stores in signingConfigs were different in the wear module and the mobile module, making them the same solved the problem.